# No compatible source was found for this media - Azure Media Services Live Streaming

Tags: azure, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, live-streaming, azure-media-services

So I am trying to live stream to Azure Media Service through my Raspberry Pi 3 + Camera Module. I found a very useful article: http://gtrifonov.com/2015/07/02/streaming-live-video-from-raspberrypi-to-azure-media-services/
I did everything the author told me. I executed the

```
sudo ~/azure_ffmpeg.save
```

at the command line and everything started going well without error.
An infinite loop of:

> frame=11736 fps= 27 q=24.0 size=   14556kB time=00:06:30.93 bitrate= 305.0kbits/

with increasing frame and constant fps of 28-31. The problem now is that when I tried to Watch Preview at Azure Portal, the error shows "No compatible source was found for this media." (I have created streaming endpoints, do not know if it matters or not.) Any suggestions/solutions?

EDIT:
Encoding Type of channel is "pass-through".

Answer (score 0):

Which browser did you use in the Azure Portal? It sounds like a playback issue in the browser, as though it could not decode the video or audio format that you are sending to it.

You can get a better debugging of the issue if you load your playback URL into this player via Chrome - https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/

See if the playback works for you there or if there are any more details on the error message.

Comment: also make sure you are sending audio!